# Can I pass a string between two javascript files?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to pass a string from one .js to another .js file? For Example, main.html contains javascript. I need to pass a string from main.html to another HTML file which loads a javascript file during run time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you're loading a completely new page (page1.html) it's not possible to pass variables directly from one JS file to another (nor is it possible to if you were loading the exact same JS file in both html pages).

But why don't you stick your string into a cookie? Depending on the browsers you have to cater to, you could also opt for localStorage/SessionStorage. Last but not least, there's always the option of passing a variable in your request URL (page1.html?mystring=foo) and then accessing it via Javascript.

Comment: function LoadXMLDocument() {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "1.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
}      I need to change 1.xml to 2,3,4,..etc based on the list clicked in different html file.

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the href of the link to your next page to add a query string. From there your javascript can grab the URL that is being used, parse off the value you're passing and be initialized with the value you want.

Usually this can be done by referencing window.location, but you can also add an  element and then your URL to the new page would look like http://wwww.yourdomain.com/page2.html?query_parameter=your_desired_string
Most modern browsers in my experience will auto-fill an input field if it has the same name as a query string parameter.
From there your javascript on the second page can grab the value from the hidden input element to get the string you want to get from one page to the next.

There may be some difficulty if you use the + symbol, I have seen some browsers interpet + as a space when coming across the URL. You would have to escape the + to get a real + before sending the string you want on the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply put the value into a cookie and reference that value to initialize the string in the second javascript file.